# Is there a way to display a PDF from an output stream from a decryption cipher

Tags: android, encryption, outputstream, pdf-rendering

I am currently working on an android application that stores sensitive documents that are encrypted on the device. When the user opens the document it decrypts it and displays it to them. I have figured out the encryption I am just not sure how to display it without saving the decrypted file and then displaying it. Is there a way to send the CipherOutputStream to the pdf renderer? Is there a way to do this or do I just have to use a cache file and is that secure? Or do I have to build my own pdf renderer for this?

This is how I am decrypting the pdf

```
      val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
      val inputStream = context.openFileInput(fileNameToConvert)
      val outputCacheFile = File(context.cacheDir, nameDecryptedFileToSave)
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key)
      CipherOutputStream(outputCacheFile.outputStream(), cipher).use {
        it.write(inputStream.readBytes())
      }
```

Comment: That depends on the sued PDF library but most require random access so in the end the save the PDF data to file or into a byte array in memory.

Comment: Ok those are good suggestions. I just hoping there was a way to do it with the built in android renderer PdfRenderer that takes in a ParcelFileDescriptor I should have been more specific. I will most likely just use the cache file though and delete it when the user exits the app, since I don't want to use a third party. Trying to keep this as native or all of the built in android tools as possible since using a 3rd party resources can make it less secure.